# DB Design - Different tables that share a common table - each has their own values

Tags: database-design

I have a  `Persons` table. This table has two tables depended on, the `Clients` and `Clerks` tables, `Persons` has many `Clerks` and `Persons` has many `Clients`

Something like this, visually:

```
Persons
|     \

Clerks Clients
```

Clients and Clerks both need a relation with `Locations` table; both the Clients and the Clerks has a latitude, longitude combination and many other geographic related elements. I'm not sure about this approach: I cannot link the Clerks and Clients table with a one to one relationship, because `Locations` will have two foreign keys from different tables.

```
Persons
|     \

Clerks Clients

 \        /
  Locations
```

Is there another approach?

Comment: Why Person, Clerk and Client are separate entities? A Person-1 (which has many Clerks and many Clients) formally may be a Clerk for Person-2, and a Client for Person-3...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another approach?

The alternative approach is to use the "Table-per-Hierarchy" design, and store all types of Persons in a single table, eg

```
create table Persons
(
  Id int primary key,
  PersonType char(6) check PersonType in ('Clerk','Client'),
  LocationId int references Locations,
  . . .
)
```